# WPF animation does not trigger iff animating Opacity from 0.0

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, font-awesome, opacity

I would like to fade in/out animate [FontAwesome.WPF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FontAwesome.WPF/) spinner icon when it starts/stops spinning. Luckily, MSDN provides almost identical example how to [Trigger an Animation on Property Change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-trigger-an-animation-when-a-property-value-changes) which uses `IsMouseOver`. Chaning the property to icon's `Spin` and opacity to `0.0` should be straightforward:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="IsExecuting"/>
<fa:ImageAwesome xmlns:fa="http://schemas.fontawesome.io/icons/" 
                 Icon="Refresh" Height="8" Width="8" 
                 Spin="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=IsExecuting}">
    <fa:ImageAwesome.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type fa:ImageAwesome}">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.0" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Spin" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger> 
            </Style.Triggers>  
        </Style>
    </fa:ImageAwesome.Style>
</fa:ImageAwesome>
```

But it does not work - nothing happens at all, spinner is invisible regardless of `Spin` property value. Curiously, the fade in/out works flawlessly, as long as the 'hidden' `Opacity` is not `0`, i.e. if I rolled back to `0.25` as in MSDN example, it would work.
What is the problem here and how can I fix it?

Comment: You should add BasedOn={StaticResource {x:Type fa:ImageAwesome}} after the TargetType of the above style.